# How to execute OSQL batch from JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, orientdb

Is it possible to execute OSQL batch from server-side function written in JavaScript in OrientDB? Attempt to do some kinda:

```
var cmd = "begin\n" +
    "let account = create vertex Account set name = 'Luke'\n" +
    "let city = select from City where name = 'London'\n" +
    "let edge = create edge Lives from $account to $city\n" +
    "commit retry 100\n" +
    "return $edge"
db.command(cmd);
```

throws `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException` exception.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL functions like this:
(please note that the `var edge` has been changed in `edg` because **edge** is a private word.)

[image]

---

BTW your `db.command(cmd);` is also slightly wrong: `command()` method needs a parameter to indicate which language to use, so it would be `db.command("sql",cmd);` .

Now, in this case it doesn't work either so, as explained above, please use SQL functions.

---

Hope it helps,

Ivan